# How to disable Firebase Realtime Database iOS write offline

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline

I had a case where firebase database return success when call `setValue()` without internet. After success, the value is not updated at the database. I'm using the code as followed (in Swift):

```
Database.database().reference().child("key").setValue("something") { (error:Error?, ref:DatabaseReference) in
        if error != nil {
            // Show error in UI
        } else {
            // Show done in UI
        }
}
```

I read the doc and it says Firebase database uses offline write. How do we disable this?

> Write data offline
>
> If a client loses its network connection, your app
> will continue functioning correctly.
>
> Every client connected to a Firebase database maintains its own
> internal version of any active data. When data is written, it's
> written to this local version first. The Firebase client then
> synchronizes that data with the remote database servers and with other
> clients on a "best-effort" basis.

p/s: I disabled the offline persistent feature

Comment: The `setValue()` completion listener will not fire for local writes. It will only fire once the data is committed (or rejected) on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is built on the premise that it handles intermittent loss of connectivity (mostly) transparently for the user and developer. There is no feature to disable local writes while the client is not connected to the server.

But you can implement this yourself by listening for `.info/connected` and suppressing write operations in your app when that location is `false`. For more on this, see [detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: I notice `.info/connected` and am try to avoid tat as it would complicate app logic. Is it the only way?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, you better use `keepSynced(false)` while app is offline.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities

```
let scoresRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "scores")
scoresRef.keepSynced(false)
```

Comment: Is it related to tat? From my understanding, keepSynced is used for downloading data and stored locally, but didn't mention including writing. Could u explain more in details?

Comment: For that case, you need to add `Alamofire` or `Reachability` to check whether device is offline or not first, then if offline, skips that block.